# Where can I find a free website for managing closed source project development?

Tags: pm-software, reporting, small-projects, bugs

Is there any free webpage/web application for managing project development with these requirements:

- Writing **public posts** of news about project (new version, new logic
  etc) - can be as blog posts.
- Simple public bug reporter.
- Private (for developer team) articles about developing.
- Page for downloading binaries of project.
- **suitable for Closed source app.**
- ***Must be Web based.***

Optionaly:

- Managing TODOs as the developing plan - it can be as a standalone main article that will be edited and formated for TODOs.
- Discussions for developer team.
- Comments on public articles.

Comment: Check out the [pm-software](http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pm-software) tag. There are plenty of other users who have asked similar questions, and you're likely to find the answers there. Also, please be sure to check out the [FAQ](http://pm.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: tried, but did not find a WEB PAGE, for CLOSED SOURCE and with PUBLIC access to articles or posts.. thats why I asked

Comment: +1 Excellent, I highlighted those points in your question so they're easy to spot. Welcome to Project Management SE, the site for expert and enthusiast project managers!

Comment: oh thanks :) might have to come in my mind

Comment: What do you mean by closed source?

Comment: Why do you want a free, closed source, product?!

Comment: @richard - closed source is the opposite of open-source eg it will be a free software product but not open-source

Comment: @Chad - why? because i dont have the money for payed websites..

Comment: @Zavael, but it being open or closed source has no bearing on if you'll have to pay for it.  I just don't get why you would eliminate all the free open source options.

Comment: aaah i get it now.. i did not mean it has to be closed source.. i just wanted to eliminate websites that force you to opensource projects like SourceForge.. i mean i dont want to have my app open source... @jmort253 edited my question and he added the closesource clausule

Comment: @Chad - maybe my interpretation was misleading for jmort253 too.. my apology, Im not native En speaker nor writer :)

Comment: It's a question about software recommendations (off-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i found a sollution after a while - [Google Sites](https://sites.google.com/) and they dont force you to have open source app.
They allow to

- create posts as announcements - public, private, something between
  that
- have todo lists - public, private...
- discussion - linked [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com)
- Dashboard like News page
- Dowload page
- Comments on pages or announcements
- plus many more feature as live view of google docs, Google calendar, widgets etc

Only the bug reporting is missing (or i didnt found), but it can be solved in the discussion or comments

Answer (score 1):

I found two answers over at stackoverflow.com:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297153/can-you-recommend-a-svn-closed-source-project-hosting-site
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683600/free-closed-source-svn-hosting

The questions are about sourcecode hosting, but the suggested sites all have project management tools included. 
Most of the time the free plans are limited, but it might be a good starting point.

Comment: thanks, i tried a few of them and they were great but most of them missed the public posts feature and the others missed something else...